# How can I improve my pronunciation between /i/ and /i:/?

Tags: pronunciation

I just recently discovered the difference between /ɪ/ and /i:/ sounds (sit vs. seat) in English.

I keep making this mistake when speaking, especially with words I already know because I learned them incorrectly.  Are there any recognized, tested methods to improve on this?

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, this question seems to be getting some negative responses because it's seen as attracting subjective, opinion-based answers, [which are discouraged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). In my opinion (heh), there can be a valid objective answer, because people *do* work on pronunciation all the time (speech therapists do it for a living). I encourage you to edit your question to emphasize that you're looking for practical, recognized methods to improve pronunciation, not just opinion and casual suggestions.

Comment: In fact, this site specifically lists requests for suggestions or recommendations as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a scientist, but I help people improve their English. I also work on improvement myself. The steps below seems to work, if used as a "routine".

1. Make it a (mental) target that you want to improve your pronunciation.
2. Speak slower (especially if you tend to speak faster). In this way, you give your brain more time to concentrate on quality.
3. Be aware that nobody is perfect - so you are not perfect either. You will make mistakes. But you will improve - so you will make mistakes less and less.
4. Make some list of (usual) words you want to practice. Examples: slip-sleep, ship-sheep, pick-peak, mint-meet... Repeat those words with a loud voice. Listen to what you say, and try to hear if the pronunciation is the way you want. *Feel free to **make "i" excessively long, just for practice**, to get used to the feeling, and to the difference.* (You might even get amused occasionally doing this. That is good.)
5. Use some voice recorder - there are many apps on the smartphones today, many even for free. Or use any device you prefer, and you have available. Record your speaking practice. Then listen to the recording. In this way, you can better understand if you pronounce the way you want.
6. To be sure you are on the right track, take some "lessons" with a teacher / tutor, where you will have another person's opinion about your improvement. Additionally, they might have additional strategies for improvement.

I use English for more than 20 years, and I still hear myself (sometimes) pronouncing wrongly. But I just do not give up. I even learned to speak slower - so people with less experience with English would be able to understand me better.

Bottom line: do not give up, keep practicing. Even if you do not succeed in a few days, you will succeed in more days.

Comment: Your #4 suggestion is particularly good... it's called the "minimal pairs" method in some academic texts on the subject, and is to my knowledge the only type of drill or exercise that actually works.